# Integer throws NullPointer exception when trying to modify it

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to generate a PDF based on data passed in through an object using Apache PDFBox.  Since there's a variable amount of data I use a variable called `volY` to keep track of the y position to write the information.  if `volY` is greater than 700, I close the Content stream I'm writing to, generate a new page and a new content stream, and start writing to a new page.  The methods I use to write to the pdf return an integer which represents the height of the string, which I add to `volY`.  For some reason when I try to access volY when iterating through the elements I get a null pointer exception.

Here is my code to generate the PDF:

```
public void generateSection(PDPage startingPage, PDPageContentStream cs, List<TestSection> sections) throws IOException {
    /*
     * TODO
     * verify list sequence integrity and reorder if not valid.
     */

    int volY = 350;
    PDPage page = startingPage;
    PDPageContentStream vcs = cs;
    // Iterate through sections
    for(int i = 0; i < sections.size(); i++) {
        if(volY > 700) {

            vcs.close();
            page = createPage();
            vcs = new PDPageContentStream(pd, page);
            volY = 50;
        }
        if(sections.get(i).isUrgent())
            cs.setNonStrokingColor(URGENT);

        drawString(sections.get(i).getType().getName(), 60, volY, vcs, page, 18);
        cs.setNonStrokingColor(REGULAR_TEXT);

        drawLine(vcs, 60, flipY(page, volY+8), 560);
        volY += 30;
        // Iterate through Items in section
        TestSection s = sections.get(i);
        for(int y = 0; y < s.getElements().size(); y++ ) {
            TestReportElement re = s.getElements().get(y);
            TestSubSection subSection = (TestSubSection)re;

            volY++;
            drawHeader(re.getTitle(), "a", volY, page, vcs);

            for(int z = 0; z < subSection.getItems().size(); z++) {
                //volY doesn't exist here for some reason?  At the very least it's not modifiable.


                if(vcs == null) {
                    System.err.println("VCS IS NULL");
                    System.exit(3);
                }
                TestInspectionItem ti = subSection.getItems().get(z);
                vcs.setNonStrokingColor(BOLD_TEXT);
                System.out.println(volY);
                drawMultipleStrings(ti.getPrompt(), volY, vcs, page, z);
                vcs.setNonStrokingColor(REGULAR_TEXT);
                for(int z1 = 0; z1 < ti.getResponses().size(); z1++) {
                    if (volY > 700) {

                        vcs.close();
                        page = createPage();
                        vcs = new PDPageContentStream(pd, page);
                        volY = 50;
                    }
                    String text = ti.getResponses().get(z1);
                    drawMultipleStrings(text, volY+15, vcs, page, z1);
                }
                if (volY > 700) {

                    vcs.close();
                    page = createPage();
                    vcs = new PDPageContentStream(pd, page);
                    volY = 50;
                }
            }

            if (volY > 700) {

                vcs.close();
                page = createPage();
                vcs = new PDPageContentStream(pd, page);
                volY = 50;
            }

        }
        // Add 70 to account for a new section.
        volY += 70;
    }
    vcs.close();
}
```

Here is the code I'm using to draw multiple strings:

```
private int drawMultipleStrings(String text, int y, PDPageContentStream cs, PDPage page, int index) {
    // Page is 900 units wide
    // Assume font size is 13
    int strSize = text.length();
    int height = 0;
    String textVal = text;
    List<String> allText = new ArrayList<>();
    int xVal = index % 2 == 0 ? 60 : 300;
    if(strSize > 40) {
        while(textVal.length() > 40) {
            for (int i = 40; i > 0; i--) {
                if (textVal.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    allText.add(textVal.substring(0, i));
                    textVal = textVal.substring(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        allText.add(textVal);
        for(int ind = 0; ind < allText.size(); ind++) {
            String s = allText.get(ind);
            if(s.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                s = s.substring(1);
                drawString(s, xVal, y+(13*ind), cs, page, 13);
            } else {
                // This should only trigger on the first iteration.
                drawString(s, xVal, y+(13*ind), cs, page, 13);
            }
            height += 13;
        }
        // Allows items to be displayed in 2 columns based on the index
        return index % 2 == 0 ? 0 : height + 32;
    } else {
        drawString(text, index % 2 == 0 ? 60: 300, y, cs, page, 13);
        return 13;
    }
}
```

This code works properly, but if I change `drawMultipleStrings(ti.getPrompt(), volY, vcs, page, z);` to `volY += drawMultipleStrings(ti.getPrompt(), volY, vcs, page, z);` It throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.writeOperand(PDPageContentStream.java:2429)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.setNonStrokingColor(PDPageContentStream.java:1316)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.setNonStrokingColor(PDPageContentStream.java:1348)
    at compliancego.report.PdfService.generateSection(PdfService.java:206)
    at compliancego.report.PdfService.generateHeader(PdfService.java:176)
    at compliancego.report.PdfService.<init>(PdfService.java:97)
    at compliancego.report.PdfService.main(PdfService.java:73)
```

At first I thought this was because some of the data didn't exist to write but it works just fine if I don't update volY.  Then I thought it was an issue with the PDPageContentStream not being created when a new page is created but the stream exists.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr 2.0.13

Comment: @GhostCat the stack trace I give here is the only stack trace that I'm given.  There is no other stack trace.  I return all the values passed to volY through the methods.  It works by generating the height and returning it so I can do something like `volY += drawMultipleStrings("Value", volY, vcs, page, index);`  Is there a way I can make this a better question?  If so I'd be happy to edit it accordingly.

Comment: Current version is 2.0.14, although I don't think this will help. The question could be improved by creating a self-working program, i.e. that we can run on our PCs. We don't know what `URGENT` (and the other color constants) is, what value it has.

Answer (score 1):

You initially create a local page content stream variable you initialize with the page content stream you received as a parameter:

```
PDPageContentStream vcs = cs;
```

Upon page change you close the current page content stream in `vcs` and then set `vcs` to a new stream on a new page:

```
if (volY > 700) {

    vcs.close();
    page = createPage();
    vcs = new PDPageContentStream(pd, page);
    volY = 50;
}
```

**But in two code lines in your loop over the `sections` you draw on `cs` instead of `vcs`:**

```
cs.setNonStrokingColor(URGENT);
...
cs.setNonStrokingColor(REGULAR_TEXT);
```

During the first page change you closed `vcs` which pointed to the same stream as `cs`. Thus, these color setting instructions are drawn on the closed stream `cs` which results in the observed `NullPointerException`.

**To fix this, use `vcs` here instead of `cs`, too.**

---

The reason why this only occurred after you changed

```
drawMultipleStrings(ti.getPrompt(), volY, vcs, page, z);
```

to

```
volY += drawMultipleStrings(ti.getPrompt(), volY, vcs, page, z);
```

most likely is that before that change `volY` never grew large enough to trigger a page change but thereafter it did.